# Can not access through RDP upon after activating the Docker on Windows Server 2016

Tags: docker, google-compute-engine, windows-server-2016

I have a brand new *Microsoft Windows Server 2016 v1607 (OS Build 14393.576)* on *Google Cloud Platform*.

I connected to machine through *RDP* and installed only **Containers** feature then ran commands below as article [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/deployment/deployment) describes.

```
Install-Module -Name DockerMsftProvider -Repository PSGallery -Force

Install-Package -Name docker -ProviderName DockerMsftProvider

Restart-Computer -Force
```

> **WARNING** I did not install none of the Hyper-V features

After the restart, I connected again through *RDP* and couldn't be able to run **Computer Management**, **Task Manager** etc. but did be able to open **Command Prompt**, **Power Shell**, **Windows Explorer**.

when I type `docker version` in *Powershell* result was

```
Client:
 Version:      1.12.2-cs2-ws-beta
 API version:  1.25
 Go version:   go1.7.1
 Git commit:   050b611
 Built:        Tue Oct 11 02:35:40 2016
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64
error during connect: Get http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.25/version: open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Then I restarted the machine and can no longer be able to connect to the machine through *RDP*.

I have done this scenario twice and both ended with same result.

Please advise.

> **UPDATE** I just tested on *Microsoft Azure Platform* server version is exactly same. `docker version` returns exactly same **Client** information.  Looks like only difference is it can also return **Server** values.

```
Client:
 Version:      1.12.2-cs2-ws-beta
 API version:  1.25
 Go version:   go1.7.1
 Git commit:   050b611
 Built:        Tue Oct 11 02:35:40 2016
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.12.2-cs2-ws-beta
 API version:  1.25
 Go version:   go1.7.1
 Git commit:   050b611
 Built:        Tue Oct 11 02:35:40 2016
 OS/Arch:      windows/amd64
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you run the docker install scripts

1. Connect to the *Windows* Instance.
2. Open a *PowerShell* terminal as an **administrator**.
3. Type and hit  `netsh netkvm setparam 0 *RscIPv4 0`
4. Type and hit  `netsh netkvm restart 0`

If your connection to *Windows* stops, reconnect to the instance.

so it will become

```
netsh netkvm setparam 0 *RscIPv4 0

netsh netkvm restart 0

Install-Module -Name DockerMsftProvider -Repository PSGallery -Force

Install-Package -Name docker -ProviderName DockerMsftProvider

Restart-Computer -Force
```

You may find more details in [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/containers/#docker_on_windows)